# iOS / Android File Decryption | How To Secure PassKey?

Tags: java, android, ios, security, encryption

I am trying to implement a secure system for iOS and Android that will transfer encrypted files from a server and decrypt on the device. The challenge I am currently trying to beat is the source code of Android app (also iOS app code decompile is possible) is decompilable. So this system was not be able to pass the penetration test.

The penetration test guys actually decompiled the whole Android app code and they managed to decrypt the files. How can I build such system that it will be secure and the files are not going to be decrypted except from the app itself?

Currently what I have is:

- We encrypt bunch of files on the server in a directory. AES-256 with a passkey.
- We encrypt the whole folder as a ePub file. Using aescrypt.com freeware utility. The file is an e-book.
- We transfer the ePub file to the device.
- We unzip the ePub file to a folder on the device. (Note that the unzipped files are still encrypted)
- We override the webview's `fileURLWithPath` (on iOS) and before webview renders the content we give webview the decrypted content.

But as I said, the encrypted contents on the disk can be decrypted decompiling the code. Also the pass key is in the app source code as well.

How should I proceed in order to create a secure system for that process?

Thanks.

Comment: In order to counteract the decompilation issue you have two choices: use a Java byte code obfuscator such as Proguard, preferably one that randomly changes the code flow. The better option would be writing the app in C, C++ or Objective-C using the Android NDK. Your penetration testers will face similar difficulties as with decompiling the iOS counterpart, it's native code. On top of that your encryption/decryption routines will gain a nice speed boost, since the Dalvik VM is notoriously slow with number crunching and your code runs directly on the CPU.

Comment: What you are describing is DRM. There are two types of DRM: the DRM that has been cracked, and the DRM that nobody has bothered cracking yet.

Comment: We ended up writing decrypting libraries in C and integrate into Android via NDK.